# How to hide EditText error after typing on textfield?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: login]

Here I first attempt to login with blank values and it successfully displayed the errors. Now I am looking to hide the error "email required" when I type a value to the email textfield. I want to remove the error message "email required" when I type the first key in the email textfield
. How can I implement such a feature to this code?

```
  textInputEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_email);
    textInputPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_password);
    login =(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);



login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(!ValidateEmail() || !ValidatePassword())

        {
            return;
        }


        String inputs = "Email : "+ textInputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        inputs +="\n";

        inputs +="Password : "+ textInputPassword.getEditText().getText();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,inputs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});



}

    private Boolean ValidateEmail() {

        String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        String emailInput = textInputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if (emailInput.isEmpty()) {
            textInputEmail.setError("Email required");
            return false;
        } else if (!emailInput.matches(emailPattern)) {

            textInputEmail.setError("Invalid Email");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputEmail.setError(null);
            textInputEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add text watcher for edit text. Then you hide `Required` error.
Check below example for better understanding.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/text_input_password"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="12dp">
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Then in your activity/fragment

```
         private EditText passwordEditText;
            private TextInputPassword textInputPassword;
         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                /* Initializing views */
                passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                /* Set Text Watcher listener */
                passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(passwordWatcher);
                textInputPassword = (TextInputLayout) 
                findViewById(R.id.text_input_password);
        }

        private final TextWatcher passwordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        textInputPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
                         textInputPassword.setError("Password Required");
                    } else{
                       textInputPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
                        textView.setText("You have entered : " + passwordEditText.getText());
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: thanks!! above code works fine..but when i erase all the values inside textfield the first character i entered on the textfield still appears in the texview message .

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextWatcher to when text is changed remove the error

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  

                @Override  
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  
                    textInputEmail.setError(null);
                }  

                @Override  
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  
                }  

                @Override  
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {  
                }  
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

just set error text to empty string

```
editText.setError("", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could control the visibility of the error like. I'm asuming you can get the reference to the error label and it's stored in a variable called `errorLabel`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  errorLabel.setVisibility( validateEmail() && validatePassword() );
}
```